# Maximize the function

Tags: proof-verification, optimization

> If $x+y+z=21$ then what is the maximum value of $(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)$?

**My attempt:**

The value of $(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)$ will be maximum iff 
$$x-6=y+7=z-4=k$$
Now, substituting $x=k+6, \ y=k-7, \ z=k+4$,
$$k+6+k-7+k+4=21$$
this gives us $k=6$
so the maximum value of $(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)$
$$6\cdot6\cdot6=216$$

I am not sure whether my answer is correct. Can somebody please help me or suggest me if I am wrong? Thanks you very much.

Comment: The tag ([tag:functional-analysis]) is intended for [questions about infinite dimensional vector space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189).

Comment: Any restriction for $x$, $y$ and $z$? When $x=z=0$, $(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)=(-6)(28)(-4)>216$. $x$ and $z$ may even be negative?

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html

Comment: You have $y=-1$.  If you allow negative numbers then, say, $x=-94,y=-107,z=21+94+105=220$ gives $2160000$

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is not correct.

Try $x=100$, $y=-45$ and $z=-34$.

The correct answer: The maximum does not exist.

Comment: but should $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers?

Comment: Check it. $x+y+z=21$.

Comment: i have checked, it's not my day Michael

Comment: Sonnhard, it's not given that our variables they are positives. By the way for non-neagative variables it's also wrong. Try $x=z=0$ and $y=21$.

Comment: if so then you are right, Michael

Answer (score 1):

> As pointed by Michael and the others, the maximum does not exist.

The following clarifications might help you find your mistake.

- The constraint $x+y=z=21$ or in general $x+y+z>0$ forces at least one of $x,y,z$ to be greater than $0$.
- Now if $x>6,y>-7,z>4$, then your the equality holds by AM-GM iff $x-6=y+7=z-4$. This gives a maximum value of $216$ at the point $(12,-1,10)$.

**Question:** But what about the other cases? See Michael's counterexamples.

**Note:** AM-GM Inequality holds only when you have nonnegative variables.

---

**Claim:** If $x,y,z \geq 0$, then $(x-6)(y+7)(z-4) \leq 672$

**Proof:** Note that $(x-6)(y+7)(z-4) \geq 0$ iff $x\geq 6, z \geq 4$ or $x\leq 6,z \leq 4$.

For the first case, let $x=6+a$ and $y=4+b$ for some $a,b \geq 0$, we get

$(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)=ab(18-a-b) \leq \left(\frac{18-a-b+a+b}{3}\right)^3 =216 $ by AM-GM Inequality as attempted by you.

By our hypothesis the second case simplifies to $0 \leq x\leq 6,0 \leq z \leq 4$.

Let $x=6-a$ and $y=4-b$ for $0 \leq a \leq 4,0 \leq b \leq 6$

$(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)=ab(18+a+b) \leq 6 \cdot 4 \ (18+6+4) = 672$

Answer (score 0):

if we assume that $$x,y,z\geq 0$$ we get that
$$(x-6)(y+7)(z-4)\le 672$$ and the equal sign holds if $$x=0,y=21,z=0$$

Comment: Actually you did a calculation mistake, it should be $672$ instead of $560$

Comment: I don't understand why you posted this answer after the first answer which shows that the problem is unbounded.

Comment: for $x,y,z\geq 0$ is the function bounded!